# Webpy AttributeError ' header key'

Tags: python, ubuntu, web.py

I recently downloaded webpy on my ubuntu machine, and I am currently having trouble with its POST function.
Here is my code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import web,interface

urls = (
    '/', 'index'
)

class index(object):
    def POST(self):
        data = web.input()
        interface.interfaceModule(data.decider)
    return "SENT TO INTERFACE"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

interface is just another class which receives the POST value, and sends it to an Arduino via Serial.

Here is the error output:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web/application.py", line     239, in process
return self.handle()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web/application.py", line 230, in handle
    return self._delegate(fn, self.fvars, args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web/application.py", line 462,    in _delegate
   return handle_class(cls)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web/application.py", line 438, in handle_class
    return tocall(*args)
  File "/var/www/cgi-bin/index.py", line 12, in POST
    interface.interfaceModule(data.decider)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web/utils.py", line 76, in _  _getattr__
    raise AttributeError, k
AttributeError: 'decider'

192.168.10.1:52225 - - [09/Dec/2016 19:41:09] "HTTP/1.1 POST /" - 500   Internal Server Error
```

I sent the post request using the Chromium app: POST-MAN, with the specified key, and an arbitrary value.

Comment: you use `data.decider` but it seems `data` doesn't have property `decider`. Use `print(data, type(data), dir(data))` to see what you have in `data`

Comment: @furus I tried to print out the object value before and yes it is empty: "<Storage {}>", as for type: <class 'web.utils.Storage'>, and the dir() shows no decider attribute. How do I go about fixing this?

Comment: it means you post wrong data - you don't send any values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means you send wrong requests - you don't send `decider` in you POST.

Try

```
import requests

r = requests.post('http://localhost:8080', data={'decider':'Hello World'})

print(r.text)
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! I see what I was doing wrong all this time with POST MAN, and HttpRequest browser plugins